# Hamiltonian graph question

Tags: graph-theory

> So I have this graph
>
> [image]
>   I am able to see that it is not Hamiltonian. However, I wish to use the following theorem :
>
> > > > If $G$ is a Hamiltonian graph, then for any non-empty proper subset $S$ of $V(G)$, $$c(G-S)\le\left|\,S\,\right|$$
>
> to show that it is not Hamiltonian. In other words, I want to delete certain vertices in $G$ such that I will end up having more components than the number of vertices deleted.
>
> I have tried very hard but I can't seem to find the right vertices to delete such that I'll have more components. Need help regarding this...

Comment: There is a difference between $H \implies C$ and $\neg H \implies \neg C$.

Comment: Ok got it thnx, guess i'll have to prove it some other way.

Comment: Proving non-hamiltonicity often involves ad-hoc arguments.  Here, the degree 2 vertices can help, because any Hamiltonian cycle will have to use the two edges incident to the corner vertices.  So how can a Hamiltonian cycle visit one of the set of 3 vertices that are not in the grid ?  There are two 2 entry points , say vertices x and y, to visit such a triplet. But one of these entry points has to be used to visit the corners.  So if x is used to visit the corners, you'll have to use y to visit the triplet, but the cycle can't exit since both x and y were used. I hope that's somehow clear !

Comment: @Sapphire The way you were approaching the problem is valid. You are using the contrapositive of the theorem listed. See also [Theorem 2](http://www.mit.edu/~miforbes/ham_cycle.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the 5 red vertices leaving behind the 6 green circled components.

[image]